# What is the API for Facebook 'profile stream' aka wall posts?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-wall

Is there an API call, and if so, which call to get the 'posts to my wall from myself and others' on Facebook? It seems like it could be filtered out of the Facebook stream API, but it's not clear how that works to me.

This link seems to imply it's possible:

http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do an FQL query like this:

```
SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = <user id> limit 50
```

You will probably want to select a few more fields, you can see what is available here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream_%28FQL%29

Answer (score 1):

Here it is.
Profile feed (Wall): https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465

You can publish stories to people who like your Open Graph Page the same way you write a Facebook post from your own wall. The stories appear in the News Feeds of people who have clicked the Like button on the Open Graph Page.

You can also publish using our API. If you associate your Open Graph Page with a Facebook app using the fb:app_id meta tag, you can publish updates to the users who have liked your pages via the Graph API.

First you need to get an access token for your app.

Check out the blog post, it covers everything you need.